# Navigation with all sub-links shown on hover

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, nav, navigationbar

I'm trying to figure out how to open all sub-menus when you hover over a menu link that has a submenu. They would open like a mega menu and be aligned under their respective menu link.

Right now I can get them to initially all open on hover but they go away as you move. I've added a codepen link here: https://codepen.io/sibarad/pen/LrvooV

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
      <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a>Browse Artworks</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item"><a>New Work</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a>All Collections</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a>Prints</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a>Arquive</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a>Our Events & Shows</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item"><a>Upcoming Events</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a>Online Show</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a>Past Events</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a>Visit Our Galleries</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item"><a>Gallery 1</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a>Gallery 2</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a>Gallery 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a>About the Artist</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a>Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The relevant CSS for desktop:

```
 .main-navigation .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
 }

.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu,
.menu-item-has-children:hover ~ .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Also since they are supposed to be in a nice tray with border, I'm wondering if there is a way of styling them not individually but as a unit.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your css. Every time you was hovering on menu it was making it `display:block` so i comment it and add one more css under this. it will make it `display:block' whenever you will click on menu as you are adding active class with it onclick

```
// .menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu,
// .menu-item-has-children:hover ~ .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
//   display: block;
// }

 .sub-menu.active{display: block;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I actually want all of the sub-navs to open at the same time when the user hovers over an element with a subnav. I want them to appear as if one unit.

Comment: But according to your HTML there is single level sub menu under every menu

Comment: You have to put all sub-menu inside one menu if you want to show them all at once